# Minlength validation in form is not working

Tags: javascript, html, angular, forms, angular2-forms

Im trying to understand that If I write validation like this why is it not working and giving me strange result, If Im typing 3 later instead of 4 and move on to next field it runs both div

> Name is required
>
> Should be min 4 length

if Im typing 4 laters and move on it displays on should be 4 length

```
<div class="form-group">
    <lable for="secondName">Second Name</lable>
    
    <input type="text" 
        ngControl='secondName'
        #secondName='ngForm' 
        id="secondName" 
        class="for-control" required
        minlength='4'>
   
    <div *ngIf='secondName.touched'>
    
    <div *ngIf='!secondName.valid'>
        Second Name is required
    </div>

    <div *ngIf='!minlength'>
        min length should be 4
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

- `minlength='4'` will not set an angular variable that you can use in the html. I assume that you want to check the length of `secondName` to be greater that 3, in which case you can write the `*ngIf` as

  ```
  <div *ngIf='secondName.length < 4'>
     min length should be 4
  </div>
  ```
- Use `[(ngModel)]` to bind the `secondName` instead of `ngControl`

  ```
  <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="secondName" >
  ```

Comment: I just wanted to know why is it happening

Comment: @blackHawk because `minlength` is not set anywhere hence will evaluate to false in the `ngIf`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what is causing the problem, but I believe that `class="for-control" required` should be `class="form-control" required`